# Create a random distribution programmatically in AnyLogic with a double array of probabilites and plot it

Tags: probability, anylogic, probability-distribution

Is it possible to create a CustomDistribution in AnyLogic with an double array interval_start and a double array probability, which is one unit smaller? It shall look like this:
CustomDistribution c = new CustomDistribution(interval_start, probability);

I could not find any constructor for this case - more specifically for probabilities. The only similar constructor I could find was this:
CustomDistribution​(double[] intervalStarts, double[] numberOfObservations)

My second question is how can I plot this distribution in AnyLogic?

Comment: What you are trying to do is create a custom probability with just 1 bin. This would not make sense, hence no constructor exists for that. Maybe add some more screenshots of the actual data and what you try to achieve. Also, always try to ask separate questions in separate issues (SOF does not work like a forum, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow ). Welcome to the community :)

Comment: @Benjamin. That isn't what he's saying. He's saying he wants to provide probabilities instead of numbers-of-observations.

Comment: ...and, since the last probability is uniquely determined by the rest, in theory you'd only have to provide N-1 probabilities (where N is the number of intervals) which is why they said "one unit smaller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom distributions just use the relative numbers of observations *as* probabilities (i.e., the ratios between them determine the probabilities). You can actually *use* probabilities (0-1 values) as "number of observed values"; "observed values" is just the way AnyLogic chose to name it.